# Problem with append in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

I have 3 output in following `jQuery.each()`, i want echo(`append`) each a of they in one tag `li`.

**Like:**

This is output $.each(): `how` & `hello` & `hi`

I want this:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="">how</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">hello</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">hi</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

But following jquery code append all 3 times in the a li, as:(i not want this)

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="">howhellohi</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">howhellohi</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">howhellohi</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'get_residence',
    data: dataString_h,
    cache: false,
    success: function (respond) {
        $.each(respond.data, function (index, value) {
            $('ol li').append('<a href="" class="tool_tip" title="ok">' + value.name[index] + '</a>');
        });
    },
    "error": function (x, y, z) {
        alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
    }
});
```

This is my respond in jquery code:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "how",
        "star_type": "5-hotel",
        "site": "www.sasaas.assa",
        "service": ["shalo", "jikh", "gjhd", "saed", "saff", "fcds"],
        "address": "chara bia paeen"
    }, {
        "name": "hello",
        "star_type": "4-motel",
        "site": "www.sasasa.asas",
        "service": ["koko", "sili", "solo", "lilo"],
        "address": "haminja kilo nab"
    }, {
        "name": "hi",
        "star_type": "3-apparteman",
        "site": "www.saassaas.aas",
        "service": ["tv", "wan", "hamam", "kolas"],
        "address": "ok"
    }]
}
```

How can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the logic you're after:

```
$.each(respond.data, function (index, value) {
    $('ol li').eq(index).append('<a href="" class="tool_tip" title="ok">' + value.name[index] + '</a>');
});
```

This will add the data to the proper list item, not the same data to all list items.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
value.name[index]
```

in your code to

```
value.name
```

because that's actually the correct code. That's actually why you use `.each()`

Comment: I changed but still is same problem

Comment: @EmmyCharles: so  the problem is somewhere else, or on your server side

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me, the problem might lie in `value.name[index]` which seems to be always equal to `howhellohi`. If you alert `value.name[index]` what do you get?If you get always  `howhellohi` the problem is in your server side function