# Problem with append json_encode

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

I want append `service` by `jQuery.each()`, but it in my js code not worked?

This is my output from PHP code:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "service": ["shalo", "jikh", "gjhd", "saed", "saff", "fcds"],
        "address": "chara bia paeen"
    }, {
        "service": ["koko", "sili", "solo", "lilo"],
        "address": "haminja kilo nab"
    }, {
        "service": ["tv", "wan", "hamam", "kolas"],
        "address": "ok"
    }]
}
```

This is is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'get_residence',
    data: dataString_h,
    cache: false,
    success: function (respond) {
        $.each(respond.data, function (index, value) {
            $('ol li').append('<a href="">' + value.service + '</a>');
        });
    },
    "error": function (x, y, z) {
        alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
    }
});
```

What do i do?

Comment: You should be seeing `<a href="">shalo,jikh,gjhd,saed,saff,fcds</a>` (since you're actually casting an array value to string). You probably want another nested `$.each` in there to grab the elements of the "service" array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with append in $.each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570273/problem-with-append-in-each)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need another $.each loop because service is an Array:

```
 $.each(respond.data, function (index, value) {
     $.each(value.service, function () {
         $('ol li').append('<a href="">' + this + '</a>');
     });
 });
```

to just format the array:

```
 $.each(respond.data, function () {
     $('ol li').append('<a href="">' + this.service.join(', ') + '</a>');
 });
```